# Remove duplicate record from custom object array

Tags: java, arraylist

So i have an interface.

```
    public interface ARecord {
            public BigInteger getAutoID();
            public String getACompId();
    }
```

and

```
    public class APPPRecord extends AbstratAPRecord implements ARecord{
        private BigInteger autoID;
        private String ACompId = null;
       //setter and getter}
```

In service,

```
    List<APPPRecord> PFRecord = null;
    while(scroll.next()){
        APPPRecord item = (APPPRecord) scroll.get(0);
        List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
        unique(APPPRecord);
        recs.addAll(APPPRecord);
```

My recs has duplicate records that I'm trying to delete and have one unique record for every duplicated recod. 
So far I have tried Set and hash set but to no avail.
Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I have tried hash code and equals.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof APPPRecord)
    {
        APPPRecord temp = (APPPRecord) obj;
        if(this.getACompId() == temp.getACompId())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (this.getACompId().hashCode());        
}
```

in service:

```
    private List< APPPRecord > unique(List< APPPRecord > list) {
    List< APPPRecord > uniqueList = new ArrayList< APPPRecord >();
    Set< APPPRecord > uniqueSet = new HashSet< APPPRecord >();
    for (APPPRecord obj : list) {
        if (uniqueSet.add(obj)) {
            uniqueList.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
}
```

Comment: Set should work. What didn't? Have you overriden `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your class?

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok. Your error is probably this:

```
 if(this.getACompId() == temp.getACompId())
```

ACompId is a String. You cannot compare Strings with `==`. Use "equals" instead:

```
if(this.getACompId().equals(temp.getACompId()))
```

`==` only compares identity, meaning that a String only `==` himself - but not `==` an `equal` String. For == to work they must be the same object, but "A" and "A" don't have to be. They can be two different Objects that just happen to have the same content.

It's easy to fall in this trap, since when you write it directly...

```
String x = "A";
String y = "A";
boolean same = x == y; // will probably be true, since the compiler can optimze it into the same object
```

But this will most likely not work for dynamic Strings that are generated at runtime. So, to make it short, never rely on "==" to compare for "equals". Only use "==" if you want to compare for "same object" (which you can do in some very specific cases, of course - Strings are often not one of them).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. I actually tried that as well but I still see duplicate results.

Comment: Well, the service code does what it is expected to, tried it with Integer.